# Javascript Dice

Tags: javascript, html

I want it to display dice image but no output? What's wrong? I choose a random number from 1-6 and it will show the face of the dice. Well it is supposed to but it's not working. I also want to display the images elsewhere not replacing the button. How do you do that?

```
<html>
<head><title>DiceBoy</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function getRandom(){
var RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var RandomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if(RandomNumber1 == 1) document.write('<img src="dice1.png">');
  else if(RandomNumber1 == 2)  document.write('<img src="dice2.png">');
  else if(RandomNumber1 == 3)  document.write('<img src="dice3.png">');
    else if(RandomNumber1 == 4)  document.write('<img src="dice4.png">');
      else if(RandomNumber1 == 5)  document.write('<img src="dice5.png">');

                  else var  document.write('<img src="dice6.png">');


}

</script>
<input type="button" value="Throw Dices" onClick="getRandom();">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code looks awful, make sure you always DRY code:

```
function getRandom(){
     var RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     var RandomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="dice' + RandomNumber1 + '.png">';
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<img src="dice' + RandomNumber2 + '.png">';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzrGh/4/

Comment: hey I dont want the button being replaced by the image

Comment: Updated. See the new fiddle.

Comment: You made a mistake shud be 2 div LOL

Comment: 2 divs? Why? I thought you only want to show 2 dice results at a time, so we can show both in a single div.

Comment: check you can't. Will be overwritten Well never mnd I did it myself

Answer (score 2):

That `var` is unnecessary. Remove it and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/rRhqn/

Next time, open your Javascript console (Ctrl+shift+J in Chrome for example) and read the errors that come up.

---

To have more control over your document, drop `document.write` and use the document object model.

Have a look at this function:

```
function writeDice(n) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'dice'+n+'.png';
    document.getElementById('dice_container').appendChild(img);
}
```

It creates an `img` element, sets its `src` depending on the parameter and appends it to an element that has the ID `dice_container`.

In your HTML, set this ID on the place where you want the images to appear.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/REPAe/

Comment: As I said I want the dice to appear elsewhere not replacing the button

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `var` on the last `else`

and for your wish to show the dices else where I will continue Cristy great implemenatation.

add an enpty div under the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Throw Dices" onClick="getRandom();">
<div id="diceImage1"> </div>
<div id="diceImage2"> </div>
```

and then use this function:

```
function getRandom(){
  var RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var RandomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

  document.getElementById("diceImage1").innerHTML = '<img src="dice' + RandomNumber1 + '.png">';
  document.getElementById("diceImage2").innerHTML = '<img src="dice' + RandomNumber2 + '.png">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra var at the end

```
else document.write('<img src="dice6.png">'); //removed the var
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
function getRandom(){
  var RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  document.getElementById("showImage").innerHTML='<img src="dice' + RandomNumber1 + '.png">';
}
```

**and in the markup**

before your button:

```
<div id="showImage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In dicee.html

`<body onload="getRandom()">`

In index.js

2 Approaches:

1. Easy one (using direct src);

```
function getRandom(){
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

  document.querySelector(".img1").src="images/dice"+randomNumber1+".png";

  document.querySelector(".img2").src="images/dice"+randomNumber2+".png";
}
```

2. According to the question (using setAttribute)

```
function getRandom(){
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

 document.querySelector(".img1").setAttribute("src","images/dice"+randomNumber1+".png");
 document.querySelector(".img2").setAttribute("src","images/dice"+randomNumber2+".png");
}
```